# How to crawl through login forms without the name attribute?

Tags: python, html, web-crawler, screen-scraping

Hopefully someone can help me with this, as you may notice by the awful title I can't really describe the issue in a format that would yield relevant google results. I'm trying to crawl through the ebay login form, and when I inspect the name attribute it is just a random 10-digit number. I'm assuming that this is a clever way to make my life difficult (ebay if you're reading this, fix your API plz) As you may have guessed, the number changes when I refresh the page. So my question is, how do I crawl through this form using python? Can I target this element with the placeholder attribute or something? I would greatly appreciate the help as I'm stumped with this one.
[heres the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJNs.png)

Comment: you still have a class to target

Comment: what libraries are you using and what is your intent?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I would normally use requests, but if I'm not mistaken you need the name or action attributes. Is there another module I should look into?How can I target it by class if submitting the form is my goal? Thanks again.